# Cannot place vmware-ovftool in the uninstall list

Tags: vmware

I tried to reinstall Ovftool into my Centos and replace it with an old version but getting a message which I don't know how to fix it.

command to uninstall it

```
vmware-installer -u vmware-ovftool
```

command to install it again

```
sudo ./VMware-ovftool-4.3.0-7948156-lin.x86_64.bundle
```

Message received :

```
Cannot place vmware-ovftool 4.3.0 in the uninstall list.
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's better to use the built-in `yum remove <package>` this **may** remove conflicting config.

Using `rpm -e <package>` is even better, if available, because it **guarantees** to remove remaining config. It will back up modified config files, but these won't interfere with future installations.

The package name for `vmware-ovftool` is `open-vm-tools` on my Ubuntu box, it may be worth checking that too, it could be the same on RHEL/CentOS/Oracle Linux as well.

Answer (score -1):

Simply install another bundle and everything back to normal.